# how to read data from mysql and used to calculate?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

When I read a column of data from mysql,like this

```
cursor = db.cursor()
query = ('SELECT GDP FROM city')
cursor.execute(query)
gdp_list = []
for GDP in cursor:
    gdp_list.append(GDP)
```

Now i get the gdp_list

```
 [(50,),
  (60,),
  (80,),
  (40,)]
```

But i find the gdp_list cannot be used to calculate because the format of element.
How can i solve the problem?

Comment: What is your expected result? It looks like you have a list of tuples. Were you expecting a list of floats or integers?

Comment: Like this [50,60,80,40]

Comment: Your problem is the results are a list of tuples. (Run `type(gdp_list[1])` to see what I mean.)

You should be able to google "tuple math numpy" to get something useful. If you get stuck with that approach, I suggest tweaking your question based on how far you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor results are always a tuple.

You need to index it, and you can rewrite that looping into list comprehension

```
cursor.execute(query)
gdp_list = [res[0] for res in cursor]
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are getting tuples instead of ints in GDP. The int you want to append is just the first element of the tuple. Simply use GDP[0] instead of GDP.

```
cursor = db.cursor()
query = ('SELECT GDP FROM selectedairport')
cursor.execute(query)
gdp_list = []
for GDP in cursor:
    gdp_list.append(GDP[0])# append only the first element of the tuple
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the tuple part to the list , You can iterate over tuple or if you want you can try this lambda approach:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x[0],gdp_list)))
```

Output wil be:

```
[50, 60, 80, 40]
```